# SOQL Clarification

Tags: soql

I am trying to find out of how many Number of location (Account object field) having each account by using below SOQL query.

```
select name, count(Numberof_locations__C) from account group by Name
```

Here some of the accounts having number of locations 6, but the query is returning only 1 for all accounts.

How to get accurate results?

Answer (score 1):

If your field Numberof_locations__C is a Number field and you want to calculate number of locations, you can use SUM() in your aggregate query.

COUNT() returns the number of rows that match the filtering conditions.